# ValueError when using long() in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, long-integer

So when I run:

```
value = long("00000000000000020000000000000002", 16)
```

I get :

```
ValueError: Value out of range: 36893488147419103234
```

I think it's because long can't take such a big hex number, but I'm not sure.

In reality I'm iterating through a file with a large amount of very big hex numbers, but this is just an example of one of the hex numbers I'm trying to parse.

I've tried using `lstrip()` to remove some of the 0's but it made no difference to the error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unable to duplicate on 2.7.13 with an even much longer number.

Comment: FYI, in Python 3 `value = int("00000000000000020000000000000002", 16)` runs fine (`int` replaces Python 2's `long`).

Comment: I'm also unable to duplicate on python2.7.12.  What version are you using specifically?  Are you sure that the `ValueError` isn't being emitted at some step further on in the processing?

Comment: @rikg09 have a try with this https://repl.it/languages/python

Comment: Unable to reproduce on Python 2.7.5, neither.

Comment: Post the full traceback.  The error message by itself is not enough information.

Answer (score 0):

The error was being caused by the variable I was trying to assign the value to, not the actual long() function.

Comment: Incorrect.  Simple assignment to a name cannot raise a Value Error.

Comment: I simplified the code before I made the question. In reality I was trying to assign the number to a protobuff field (not sure if thats the right name for it), which wasn't made to take such a number. As soon as I switched to just assigning it to a python var, no error happen. In the end I realised I didn't even need to store the number in there, so I didn't matter in the end...

Sorry for all the confusion